# Изменения цвета анимации без альфа-каналов

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть анимация перехода цвета, но нужно что бы прозрочность (т.е. альфа-каналы) менялись кодом, как только я убираю ключи для альфа-каналов в анимации то это значения постоянно равно нулю, даже если во время паузы изменить на 255, то на след. кадре уже будет ноль, что я могу сделать?

Comment: c анимациями и скринами будет более понятно:)

Comment: @TEA на видео будет более понятнее, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ziN-ToETIaY&feature=youtu.be , там видно что при изменении из анимации всегда будет одно значения альфа-каналов, а если без анимации то всегда ноль, кодом я меняю все значения которые вообще есть на кубе, но альфа-каналы не меняються